# List all regions available for my account per service in AWS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am developing an NestJs app where I need the list of regions available for my account for each service(as regions could vary depending on service).

I had tried using the aws-regions npm package but that gives a list of all available accounts in AWS and is causing unnecessary API calls.

All the regions are not opted for in my account.So I need only the ones opted for and as per service.

For example

ec2 - us-east-1 and us-east-2

ebs - us-east-1 and us-west-2

Comment: Availability of service depends on the region you select, not on the account. A service has nothing to do with the account.

Comment: All the regions are not opted for in my account.So I need only the ones opted for and as per service.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html), as shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/)? It looks like it is available through the SDKs (including JavaScript).

Using the CLI, it looks like this, for one service (Athena, in this case) to get the list of regions. I'm not sure if it accounts for opt-in services, you would have to test that to find out.

```
$ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
  --path /aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/athena/regions --output json | \
  jq '.Parameters[].Value'
```

Comment: No was not very helpful in getting the regions associated with service.